# using multiple else blocks in conditional

Tags: javascript, codepen

I'm not quite sure why my code is not working. Can anyone help?
javascript

```
/*if statements below*/

if (hours > 18) {
  greeting = "Good Evening"
}

else if(hours > 12) {
  greeting = "Good Afternoon";
}

else {
 greeting = "Good Morning";   
} 
else  {
 greeting = "Welcome Night Owl"; 
}
```

Comment: Only one `else` per `if` statement. You cannot have an `else` after an `else`

Comment: Adding to VLAX's comment it could help you if you could tell us the missing condition for Good Morning, and we might be able to suggest something better.

Comment: The good morning condition is supposed to catch everything from 12 and below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must learn about basic programming first for javascript, I will suggest you visit https://javascript.info
You should try this hope it makes sense

```
const hours = 12;

if (hours <= 18 && hours > 12) {
greeting = "Good Evening"
}

else if(hours == 12) {
greeting = "Good Afternoon"
}

else if(hours >= 4 && hours < 12){
greeting = "Good Morning"

} 
else{
greeting = "Welcome Night Owl"
}
console.log(greeting);
```

Answer (score 3):

If it was an else if ladder it should be like below

```
if (hours > 18) greeting = "Good Evening";
else if (hours > 12) greeting = "Good Afternoon";
else if (your condition missing here) greeting = "Good Morning";
else greeting = "Welcome Night Owl";
```

for more information check [this url](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/if-else-statement-in-javascript/).